# How to replace urls from a string into an anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

```
//js

 var content ="welcome  http://www.yahoo.com?career hi http://www.yahoo.com http://www.yahoo.com  http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator ";

//******************************************************************************//
//data coming from server

 var distinctURLs = ["http://www.yahoo.com?career" , "http://www.yahoo.com" , "http://www.yahoo.com" , "http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator" ];

//******************************************************************************//

//replacing with anchor tag
 for (var j = 0; j < distinctURLs.length; j++) {
     content = content.replace(new RegExp( distinctURLs[j], 'g' ), "<a href='" +    distinctURLs[j] + "'>" + distinctURLs[j] + "</a>");
 }
```

so in above situation first i'm finding urls from `var content` and replacing with `<a>` tag but its not working properly.

```
//output  should be

welcome <a href="http://www.yahoo.com?career">http://www.yahoo.com?career</a> hi  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a > <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a> <a href="http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator">http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator</a>
```

Using `replace` and `new RegExp` its not getting what expected

Here u can refer [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/r54v3ncd/)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this simple using **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex

```js
var content ="welcome  http://www.yahoo.com?career hi http://www.yahoo.com http://www.yahoo.com  http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator ";

document.write(content.replace(/http:\/\/[^\s]+/g,'<a href="$&">$&</a>'))
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hD5lT2/1)**

**UPDATE:**

Or with your code you can do

```js
var content = "welcome  http://www.yahoo.com?career hi http://www.yahoo.com http://www.yahoo.com  http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator ";
var distinctURLs = ["http://www.yahoo.com?career", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://10.179.105.223:81/Person.aspx?accountname=MHC%5CAdministrator"];
document.write(content.split(/\s+/).map(function(v) {
  return distinctURLs.indexOf(v) == -1 ? v : '<a href="' + v + '">' + v + '</a>';
}).join(' '));
```

1. Split the content using **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**
2. Iterate over the using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**
3. Check value is in array `distinctURLs` using **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** and return required value
4. Join the array value by space using **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

Comment: but based on distinctURLs  which is getting from server i have to replace only those into a `<a>` tag